# Remove duplicate row if column 2 exist

Tags: awk, sed

I am working with sample data, over 10k lines, similar to the following:

```
hxxp://google.com 
hxxp://google.com "Seen"
hxxp://yahoo.com "Check again"
hxxp://yahoo.com 
hxxp://about.com
hxxp://x.com
hxxp://y.com
hxxp://z.com
hxxp://reddit.com
hxxp://a.com "good"
hxxp://a.com
hxxp://b.com "good"
hxxp://c.com
hxxp://c.com "good"
hxxp://c.com
```

I've been trying to find a way to achieve these results:

```
hxxp://google.com "Seen"
hxxp://yahoo.com "Check again"
hxxp://about.com
hxxp://x.com
hxxp://y.com
hxxp://z.com
hxxp://reddit.com
hxxp://a.com "good"
hxxp://b.com "good"
hxxp://c.com "good"
```

In the sample data, there might be a duplicate row. If there is a duplicate row, delete the row that is missing a second column. The delimiter is space.

```
awk -F' ' '!seen[$1]++' dupe.txt > clean.txt
```

That doesn't seem to be the right one liner for me.

Comment: Do you need to keep the order of the lines?

Comment: No, I plan to sort the list alphabetical once I am done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ LC_ALL=C sort -r <file | LC_ALL=C sort -k1,1 -us
hxxp://a.com "good"
hxxp://about.com
hxxp://b.com "good"
hxxp://c.com "good"
hxxp://google.com "Seen"
hxxp://reddit.com
hxxp://x.com
hxxp://y.com
hxxp://yahoo.com "Check again"
hxxp://z.com
```

The first `sort` sorts the file in reverse order, using the whole line as the sorting key.  This will result in the intermediate result

```
hxxp://z.com
hxxp://yahoo.com "Check again"
hxxp://yahoo.com
hxxp://y.com
hxxp://x.com
hxxp://reddit.com
hxxp://google.com "Seen"
hxxp://google.com
hxxp://c.com "good"
hxxp://c.com
hxxp://c.com
hxxp://b.com "good"
hxxp://about.com
hxxp://a.com "good"
hxxp://a.com
```

given the example data.  Notice how the lines containing extra annotation always comes before the corresponding lines with no extra annotation.

The second `sort` only produces lines whose sorting key is unique.  We use only the first field (the URL) as the sorting key.  We also ask `sort` to use a "stable" sorting algorithm with `-s`.  This means that the order of lines with identical keys will not change from what's in the input.

The `-u` and `-s` combination gives you only the lines with extra annotation for the URLs that are repeated.

The `LC_ALL=C` bit is to makes sure `sort` gets a sane locale so that the lines sorts correctly for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

if your example contains all states of yours and assumes your file named Sample.data:

```
grep " " Sample.data > Result
cut -d' ' -f1 Result > FirstCol
grep Sample.data -v -f FirstCol >> Result
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
awk '
    !($1 in a) || NF > 1 {a[$1] = $0} 
    END {for (url in a) print a[url]}
' dupe.txt
```

The order of the lines will not be preserved.

This will keep the order but requires 2 passes over the file:

```
awk '
    NR == FNR {
        if (!($1 in a) || NF > 1) {a[$1] = $0} 
        next
    }
    $0 == a[$1]
' dupe.txt dupe.txt
```

Comment: Ran that and output to clean.txt. Then "sort - u clean.txt > final.txt" and I noticed that there are duplicates (two rows with only 1 second column).

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Can you update your sample data to help reproduce the problem?

Comment: Updated with more sample data. From my previous note, I ran your argument and noticed it left duplicate entries.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -lane '
    push @h, $F[0] if ! exists $h{$F[0]};
    $h{$F[0]} = $_ if ! exists $h{$F[0]} || @F > 1;
    }{ print $h{$_} for @h;
' dupe.txt > clean.txt
```

**Explanation:**

- `@h` stores the order in which the keys, viz., the first fields are encountered.
- `%h` is the hash which is keyed on the first field, `$F[0]` and the corresponding values are the lines in toto.
- The values of the hash `%h` are updated everytime a new key is seen OR when we see an old key but the line has more than one field, in which case it is ripe for updation.
- At the `eof`, we simply loop over the keys stored in the array `@h` and pull out the corresponding values and take to the stdout.

**Output:**

```
xxp://google.com "Seen"
hxxp://yahoo.com "Check again"
hxxp://about.com
hxxp://x.com
hxxp://y.com
hxxp://z.com
hxxp://reddit.com
hxxp://a.com "good"
hxxp://b.com "good"
hxxp://c.com "good"
```